# Value passed to function was changed

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, vga

I'm trying to write simple os to better understandig how OSes works, I have problem with my screen lib, I have function to clearing screen:

```
#define VGA_ADDRESS 0xb8000
#define MAX_ROWS 25
#define MAX_COLS 80
#define SUPREMACY_TTY_COLOR 0x0f
#define RED_ON_WHITE 0xf4

/* Screen i/o ports */
#define REG_SCREEN_CTRL 0x3d4
#define REG_SCREEN_DATA 0x3d5


void clear_screen() {
    int screen_size = MAX_COLS * MAX_ROWS;
    int i;
    char* vga_mem = (char*)VGA_ADDRESS;

    for (i = 0; i < screen_size; i++) {
        vga_mem[i*2] = ' ';
        vga_mem[i*2+1] = TTY_COLOR;
    }
    set_cursor_offset(get_offset(0, 0));
}
int get_offset(int col, int row) { return 2 * (row * MAX_COLS + col); }
```

But os is going to bootloop, when I run that function in kernel, I have started debuging with gdb and it shows that function was called as:

```
get_offset(0,0);
```

but in function there is strange values:

```
get_offset (col=-268370093, row=-268377405) at kernel/drivers/screen.c:103
```

Do anyone knows where is the problem?

@edit, I had added defines, the only thing I've doing is call clear_screen() from kernel main()

Comment: Where are col and row declared/initialized/loaded?

Comment: The loop in `clear_screen()` treats `vga_mem` as if it is an array of `2*screen_size` characters.    If that isn't the case, it is overwriting memory it shouldn't.   Beyond that, it is not possible to guess what your problem is - read up on providing a [mcve].